# How to access NSArray instance belonging to MyDocument in another xib?

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, nsarraycontroller, nsdocument, nswindowcontroller

In my document application I subclassed an NSArrayController which I referenced in MyDocument.xib bounding its content to **File's Owner.entries**.

entries is an NSArray I expose as an attribute of MyDocument class this way:

```
@interface MyDocument : NSDocument {
    NSArray *entries;
}

-(NSArray *)entries;
-(void)setEntries:(NSArray *)newEntries;
@end
```

This works perfectly fine. Good.

Now I have designed another .xib, CSVEntries.xib which I open via a NSMenuItem through a NSWindowController and again, this works smoothly.

I can't figure out how to make this new window display the content of the MyDocument.entries instance in an NSTableView.

I have tried many things, **but the problem basically is that any NSArrayController I put on CSVEntries.xib can not be bound to MyDocument.entries**: CVSEntries.xib File's Owner is referring to something else not MyDocument (which is logical, I guess).

I also tried to add a copy of the NSArray instance to the NSWindowController which opens CVSEntries.xib, but since the window get's instantiated only when the user clicks on the menu, I ended up having an empty array.

I am searched around the Internet but could not find an appropriate answer, I just would like to figure out the proper way to approach the issue, I am sure two windows can communicate between eachother, maybe accessing their common parent (NSApplication instance)?

All newbie questions, I know :)

### Update

I think I figured out where to look but still not how to. I think I have to make sure second window File's Owner is MyDocument but in the NSWindowController  initWithWindowNibName:owner: I can't understand how to specify the MyDocument instance as the owner. Specifying it only in the xib file File's Owner seems not enough.

### Update 2

Uhm...I am starting to think that I need to have two NSWindowController instances both instantiated by my NSDocument subclass (default MyDocument). With those in place maybe both the NSWindowControllers will have access to the MyDocument.entries NSArray and the  two windows xib files will be able to be bound to File's Owner.entries.

Can someone confirm this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reply to my own question here, basically stating that I have realized what I was asking is very much dependent on what the File's Owner is bound to. The design I implemented was not correct and I am therefore redesigning it to achieve my purpose.

Thanks everyone anyway, even no answers are an answer :)